# Proof of Lemma 6.5 in Scholze's Perfectoid Spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, perfectoid-spaces

In the proof of Lemma 6.5(approximation lemma) in [Scholze's Perfectoid Spaces](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/PerfectoidSpaces.pdf),
I have the following *three* questions about $h = f - g^\sharp_c$ and $g^\sharp_{c'}$.
(Maybe it's something you'll find out soon.)

1. **Why** does $h$ lie almost in the $\varpi$-adic completion of
   $$
   \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}[1/p] , 0 \leq i \leq 1} \varpi^{c + 1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c)} \left(\frac{g^\sharp_c}{\varpi^c} \right)^i R^\circ_{\mathrm{deg}=d-di}
   $$
   instead of the $\varpi$-adic completion of
   $$
   \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}[1/p]} \varpi^{c + 1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c)} \left(\frac{g^\sharp_c}{\varpi^c} \right)^i R^\circ_{\mathrm{deg}=d} \ .
   $$
   I can't help but think that $h$ lies almost in the later one because $h$ is a homogeneous element of degree $d$ in $R^\circ$.
   I thought that $(g^\sharp_c/\varpi^c)$ is a element of degree $d$ in $R^\circ \langle (g^\sharp_c/\varpi^c)^{1/p^\infty} \rangle$, but isn't the degree defined only for the variable $T_i$?
2. For representation
   $$
   h = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}[1/p] , 0 \leq i \leq 1} \varpi^{c + 1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c')} \left(\frac{g^\sharp_c}{\varpi^c} \right)^i r_i \  ,
   $$
   I could take $s_i \in R^{\flat +}$ homogeneous of degree $d-di$ such that $r_i - s_i^\sharp \in \varpi R^+$, *except* for the condition $s_i \rightarrow 0$.
   These $s_i$ and $r_i$ are just the same modulo $\varpi$, so I don't know if $s_i$ will also approach $0$ when $r_i$ approaches $0$.
   I thought I was going to replace each $s_i$ inductively, but I couldn't.
   **Why** can we choose the $s_i$ that $s_i \rightarrow 0$ also satisfies?
3. For claim $|f(x)-g^\sharp_{c'}(x)| \leq |\varpi|^{1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c')}|f(x)|$
   in case $|f(x)| > |\varpi|^c$,
   the paper said it is enough to show that
   $$
   \left| \left( (\varpi^\flat)^{c + 1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c')} \left( \frac{g_c}{(\varpi^\flat)^c} \right)^i s_i \right)^\sharp (x) \right| \leq |\varpi|^{1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c')} |f(x)| \  .
   $$
   I understood the proof of this inequality
   and easily show that
   $$
   |f(x)-g^\sharp_{c'}(x)| \leq \max(|\varpi|^{1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c')}|f(x)| , |g^\sharp_c(x) - g^\sharp_{c'}(x)|) \  .
   $$
   However, since $\sharp \colon R^\flat \rightarrow R$ is not additive, $|g^\sharp_c(x) - g^\sharp_{c'}(x)| \leq |\varpi|^{1 - \epsilon + \epsilon(c')}|f(x)|$ could not be shown.
   **Why** is it enough to show that inequality.

(This is my first post here, so I apologize if there is anything I am not doing right.)